# Running rspec tests (via guard) on remote instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, cucumber, guard

probably my use-case is specific, but i'm sure i'm not the only one.

I have quite big Rails application, full of Rspec/Cucumber tests. Usually it takes like 30-40 minutes to run everything from scratch on Intel i5. Yes, we are using guard, so it's not every time from very beginning. But it's annoying anyway, and i want to distribute load somehow.

Also i have another development workstation with i7, and my idea to run guard loop on it. This way, i need something to automate Rspec/Cucumber tests running via guard on remote machine, but general behaviour should be the same: i'm changing something, guard runs test for changed part on remote workstation without any additional movements from my side. I don't want to push to repo during development, of course we are using CI and local CI will be not very reasonable. And of course we are using parallel_tests, so my question not about sharing load between CPU cores.

Ideas and suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could share the files with the fast computer (via smb f.e.) and run the tests on the remote computer and check it via ssh?

Comment: It was my initial idea too. I believe setup will be tricky a little. But i'll try.

Answer (score 0):

You could mount your project working directory on the Remote machine and start Guard there, preferably over SSH so you see the console output. In addition you could use the GNTP notifier and send notifications from the remote machine to your development machine:

`Ruby
notification :gntp, :host => 'development.local', :password => 'secret'`